# Modify the parent prototype.init() function

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm curious if I can modify a class prototype.init() function since I want to extend a library and to do that I have to add some new variables into the initialization of the class.

I've done prototypical inheritance like this:

`function Extension() {};
Extension.prototype = Toolbar.prototype;
Extension.prototype.constructor = Extension;`

And now I want to initialize the Parent.prototype.init with some extra variables from my Extension.
What's a good way of doing this?

Comment: **THIS IS A BAD IDEA**: Modifying objects supplied by other libraries is a surefire way to unexpected bugs and problems. Consumers don't expect things to magically change behind the scenes, consider taking their classes and `extends`ing them (or using the traditional `Object.create()` method in ES5 or below) in your code, and supply that via your library.

Comment: The problem is that I gotta use vanilla js for the moment

Comment: Wait, do you want to actually modify `Toolbar`'s `init`, or do you want `Extension` to have a function that calls `Toolbar`'s `init` (and `Extension`'s function takes extra args, but passes the expected args into the original `init`)?

Comment: I want the second one

Answer (score 0):

This step is incorrect:

```
Extension.prototype = Toolbar.prototype;
```

This means that your `Extension` does not extend `Toolbar` -- it actually shares a prototype, so that anything you add to the `Extension`'s prototype will be added to `Toolbar`'s prototype as well. (Certainly this is not what you want!)

Instead, do:

```
Extension.prototype = Object.create(Toolbar.prototype);
```

so that `Extension` prototype is a brand new object that inherits properties from `Toolbar`'s prototype. Modifying this new object will not have an unwanted upstream effect on `Toolbar.prototype`.

To add prototype properties, simply add them to `Extension.prototype`:

```
Extension.prototype.someExtensionAction = function(someParam) {
    return 100 + this.init(someParam);
}
```

Then you can access these properties on `Extension` instances:

```
var myExtensionInstance = new Extension();
myExtensionInstance.someExtensionAction(17);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way of doing what I wanted.

It's pretty easy now that I know how apply() works.

```
var parentInit = Parent.prototype.init;

Toolbar.prototype.init = function()
{
    parentInit .apply(this, arguments);
    // Your code here
};
```